# Video slideshow

Tags: metabox, video-player

I have a custom post type using caroufredsel and it works alright but I´d like to add videos too.
My current code is:

// Initialize Slider

```
function ikos_slider_initialize() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    $j(function() {
$j('#carousel').carouFredSel({
    responsive: true,
    items: {
    visible: 1,
    width: 900,
    height: 500
     },

    pagination: '#pager'
   });
   });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'ikos_slider_initialize' );
```

// Create Slider

```
function ikos_slider_template() {

    // Query Arguments
    $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'slides',
                'posts_per_page'    => 5
            );  

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Check if the Query returns any posts
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  ?>

        <!-- begin slider -->
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="carousel">
            <?php       
            // The Loop
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div id="item">

                    <?php  
                    // Check if there's a Slide URL given and if so let's a link to it
                if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ikos_slideurl', true) != '' ) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ikos_slideurl', true ) ); ?>">
                <?php }



                // The Slide's Image
                echo the_post_thumbnail('slider'); 

                // Close off the Slide's Link if there is one
                if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'ikos_slideurl', true) != '' ) { ?>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>




        </div> <!-- end item -->
            <?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
                    </div><!-- end carousel-wrapper -->
<div id="pager"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- end slider wrap -->

    <?php }

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

So, I´d like to be able to add videos (youtube,wordpress,vimeo, any solution will do)

I tried adding a metabox with the code found here: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/youtube-and-vimeo-video-gallery-with-wordpress/

but I got the player displaying errors all the time..

Is there a way to add a metabox and how to display it inside the item in the slider content?
I tried pasting inside the metabox the shortcode that wordpress generates [video] but it wont work. When I save the metabox strips everything after the =. (It shows only this: [video flv=)

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got this working adding a text metabox for the youtube id.

Then added this lines before the link in the slider just below the   opening tag:

```
<?php  
 if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'video', true) != '' )
    { 
  $video= get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'video', true);  
?>
```

Here goes the embed code but we replace with `<?php echo $video;?>` in every place where the ID of the video is.

Like this

`<object width="760" height="427.5">
  <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $video;?>?controls=0&start=4&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&theme=light&version=3"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/<?php echo $video;?>?controls=0&start=4&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&theme=light&version=3" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="760" height="427.5"></embed>
</object>`

I had to add the  instead the iframe because it closed all my tags and everything broke.

Hope this helps someone.